# How working system in getView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, view, baseadapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_adapter, parent, false);
        }

        textViewLeft= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textViewRight= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        textViewLeft.setText(title[position]);
        textViewRight.setText(str[position]);

        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(position==(0)||position==(1)||position==(2)||position==(5)){
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (textViewRight.getText().equals("ok")) imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
            if (textViewRight.getText().equals("error")) imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
            textViewRight.setText("");
        }

        if (position==8){
            textViewRight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        }
        if (position>10){
            textViewLeft.setText("");
        }

        return view;
    }
```

In my list when you scroll down the first time, the text in the 8 position is changed to red. If you scroll listView 5 times up and down, then my text, will change color on #ff0000. What is wrong I do ?. It seems all right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to set the color to black if it is not in position 8.

```
if (position==8){
        textViewRight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
}
else {
       textViewRight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
```